# Are serialized objects stored to disk or memory?

Tags: java, android, serialization

this is my first post. I will try to make it as good as posible.
I'm developing a simple game where I'm using Serializable to keep the state of the game on Portrait and Lanscape switching. This works fine but now I want to add a "Resume game" button in my menu activity (SplashScreen.java).

My first question is; Can I use the same allready serialized objects to resume my game even after the game has been closed and restarted? In other words, will the saved state be lost at finish()?
There are three classes MainActivity, SplashScreen (menu), Board (object)

Second question: How can I pick up on the last state from my menu using a button?

In my MainActivity.java I've got this:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("board", board);
    outState.putSerializable("moveCounter", moveCounter);
}

// When onCreate is called, bring back saved state if any
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Board oldState = (Board) savedInstanceState
                .getSerializable("board");
        int oldMoveCounter = savedInstanceState.getInt("moveCounter");
        if (oldState != null) {
            board = oldState;
            moveCounter = oldMoveCounter;
        }
    }
```

In my object class Board.java I've got this:

```
public class Board implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4416703215631262818L;
...
... }
```

Comment: `SharedPreferences` are what you need.  Serialized objects may or may not exist on disk (that happens at a level lower than your app in the Dalvik VM) but certainly should not be used to persist state between instances of your application.  You could however write a serialized object to your own file but why bother since `SharedPreference` takes care of it?

Comment: I see, that was my other plan. Looks like I'm not able to recycle that part of my code then. This will be a good opportunity to learn SharedPreferences for me. Thank you Simon

Comment: whether you use serializables or parcelables, neither auto-saves itself.  It just means it can be converted to binary (a single byte array) and reconstructed from the same, which is a precondition to saving it.

Comment: I've decided to use Serializable for now, but will have a look at ParceLabels later, thank you. About the SharedPreferences, which of my classes should do the storing and editing? The object is created in my MainActivity so that's my guess.

Answer (score 0):

First, performance-wise it's better to use `Parcelable` instead of `Serializable`, so try to make your entities `Parcelable`. Here's a [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) to the documentation which also presents a simple example of making a class `Parcelable`.

Second, there are several persistence options in Android and you should pick one that suits your use case best. Here's a [good document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) that describes them all.